# Problem with for loop stopping while checking Poker Hand

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, poker

I am creating a game of texas hold 'em, if you know poker it's simple enough.

I've working on a SevenCardHand class that basically takes an ArrayList of 7 cards in the constructor. I am creating algorithms for to find the rank of a 7 card hand (whether it is a flush, straight, pair, three of a kind ...)

But the odds of some hands happening are very low, so to test this I want to automatically deal a whole bunch of hands. So I am looping through creating new SevenCardHands and printing whether or not they are a flush (is the one I'm testing right now)

The problem is that it won't let me create more than 7 hands with that for loop. The program doesn't terminate, but it doesn't make any more progress. No matter what I've done it won't make more than seven before freezing.

Here is the code from my Card, DeckOfCards, HoldEmDriver, and SevenCardHand classes

Class `HoldEmDriver.java`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HoldEmDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        DeckOfCards theDeck = new DeckOfCards();
        TableCards table = new TableCards();
        SevenCardHand seven = new SevenCardHand();
        ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList();


        for(int j=0; j<7; j++) {
            cards.clear();
            for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
                cards.add(theDeck.dealCard());
            }
            seven = new SevenCardHand(cards);
            System.out.println(""+seven+seven.hasFlush());
        }


public enum Card {

    ACEOFSPADES(1, "Spades"),
    TWOOFSPADES(2, "Spades"),
    THREEOFSPADES(3, "Spades"),
    FOUROFSPADES(4, "Spades"),
    FIVEOFSPADES(5, "Spades"),
    SIXOFSPADES(6, "Spades"),
    SEVENOFSPADES(7, "Spades"),
    EIGHTOFSPADES(8, "Spades"),
    NINEOFSPADES(9, "Spades"),
    TENOFSPADES(10, "Spades"),
    JACKOFSPADES(11, "Spades"),
    QUEENOFSPADES(12, "Spades"),
    KINGOFSPADES(13, "Spades"),
    ACEOFCLUBS(1, "Clubs"),
    TWOOFCLUBS(2, "Clubs"),
    THREEOFCLUBS(3, "Clubs"),
    FOUROFCLUBS(4, "Clubs"),
    FIVEOFCLUBS(5, "Clubs"),
    SIXOFCLUBS(6, "Clubs"),
    SEVENOFCLUBS(7, "Clubs"),
    EIGHTOFCLUBS(8, "Clubs"),
    NINEOFCLUBS(9, "Clubs"),
    TENOFCLUBS(10, "Clubs"),
    JACKOFCLUBS(11, "Clubs"),
    QUEENOFCLUBS(12, "Clubs"),
    KINGOFCLUBS(13, "Clubs"),
    ACEOFDIAMONDS(1, "Diamonds"),
    TWOOFDIAMONDS(2, "Diamonds"),
    THREEOFDIAMONDS(3, "Diamonds"),
    FOUROFDIAMONDS(4, "Diamonds"),
    FIVEOFDIAMONDS(5, "Diamonds"),
    SIXOFDIAMONDS(6, "Diamonds"),
    SEVENOFDIAMONDS(7, "Diamonds"),
    EIGHTOFDIAMONDS(8, "Diamonds"),
    NINEOFDIAMONDS(9, "Diamonds"),
    TENOFDIAMONDS(10, "Diamonds"),
    JACKOFDIAMONDS(11, "Diamonds"),
    QUEENOFDIAMONDS(12, "Diamonds"),
    KINGOFDIAMONDS(13, "Diamonds"),
    ACEOFHEARTS(1, "Hearts"),
    TWOOFHEARTS(2, "Hearts"),
    THREEOFHEARTS(3, "Hearts"),
    FOUROFHEARTS(4, "Hearts"),
    FIVEOFHEARTS(5, "Hearts"),
    SIXOFHEARTS(6, "Hearts"),
    SEVENOFHEARTS(7, "Hearts"),
    EIGHTOFHEARTS(8, "Hearts"),
    NINEOFHEARTS(9, "Hearts"),
    TENOFHEARTS(10, "Hearts"),
    JACKOFHEARTS(11, "Hearts"),
    QUEENOFHEARTS(12, "Hearts"),
    KINGOFHEARTS(13, "Hearts");

    /**The value of the card Ace-King */
    private int cardValue;
    /** The suit of the card SCDM */
    private String cardSuit;


    /**
     * Creates a card object with a suit and value
     * @param cardValue the cards value
     * @param cardSuit the cards suit
     */
    private Card(int cardValue, String cardSuit) {
        this.cardValue = cardValue;
        this.cardSuit = cardSuit;
    }

    /** Checks if this card is the same card as other
     * @param other Another card
     * @return True if the same, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isSameCard(Card other) {
        if(other.cardValue == cardValue && cardSuit.equals(other.cardSuit)) {
            return true;
        } return false;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return This cards value Ace-King
     */
    public int getCardValue() {
        return cardValue;
    }

    /**
     * Gets this cards suit
     * @return The card's suit
     */
    public String getCardSuit() {
        return cardSuit;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if two cards have the same suit
     * @param other The other card
     * @return True if same suit, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isSameSuit(Card other) {
        if(this.cardSuit.equals(other.cardSuit)) {
            return true;
        } return false;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if a card is followed by another card
     * 2 followed by 3, 10 followed by Jack
     * @param other The card to be compared with
     * @return True if other's cardValue is 1 higher than this card
     * False otherwise
     */
    public boolean isFollowedBy(Card other) {
        if(this.cardValue==other.cardValue-1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Checks if a card has the same value as another card
     * @param other The card to compare with
     * @return True if same value, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isSameValue(Card other) {
        if(this.cardValue==other.cardValue) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



    /**
     * Returns the card in readable format
     * Ace of Hearts
     * 7 of Clubs
     * 
     */
    public String toString() {
        String card = "";
        if(cardValue == 1) {
            card = card + "Ace ";
        } else if(cardValue == 11) {
            card = card + "Jack ";
        } else if(cardValue == 12) {
            card = card + "Queen ";
        } else if(cardValue == 13) {
            card = card + "King ";
        } else {
            card = card + cardValue+" ";
        }
        if(cardSuit.equals("Spades")) {
            card = card + "of Spades";
        } else if(cardSuit.equals("Clubs")) {
            card = card + "of Clubs";
        } else if(cardSuit.equals("Hearts")) {
            card = card + "of Hearts";
        } else if(cardSuit.equals("Diamonds")) {
            card = card + "of Diamonds";
        }
        return card;
    }


}
```

Class `DeckOfCards.java`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class DeckOfCards {

    private ArrayList<Card> dealtCards= new ArrayList();
    private Random random = new Random();

    /**
     * Makes a Deck with no cards yet dealt
     */
    public DeckOfCards() {

    }

    /**
     * Deals a random card from the deck that hasn't been
     * dealt already, and adds that card to dealtCards
     * @return A unique Card object randomly chosen
     */
    public Card dealCard() {
        Card newCard = Card.values()[random.nextInt(52)];
        while(isAlreadyDealt(newCard)) {
            newCard = Card.values()[random.nextInt(52)];
        }
        dealtCards.add(newCard);
        return newCard;
    }


    /**
     * Checks if a card has already been dealt
     * @param theCard The card to check
     * @return True if the card has been dealt, otherwise false
     */
    public boolean isAlreadyDealt(Card theCard) {
        boolean isDealt = false;
        for(int i=0; i<dealtCards.size(); i++) {
            if (theCard.isSameCard(dealtCards.get(i))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Class `SevenCardHand.java`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SevenCardHand {

    ArrayList<Card> allCards = new ArrayList();

    public SevenCardHand(ArrayList<Card> holeCards, ArrayList<Card> tableCards) {
        if(holeCards.size()!=2 || tableCards.size()!=5) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        allCards.addAll(holeCards);
        allCards.addAll(tableCards);
        allCards.sort(new CardComparator());
    }

    public SevenCardHand() {
    }

    public SevenCardHand(ArrayList<Card> sevenCards) {
        if(sevenCards.size()!=7) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        allCards.addAll(sevenCards);
        allCards.sort(new CardComparator());
    }


    public ArrayList<Card> getAllCards(){
        return allCards;
    }


    public String toString() {
        allCards.sort(new CardComparator());
        return ""+allCards;
    }


    public boolean hasRoyalFlush() {

    }



    public boolean hasStraightFlush() {


    }


    public boolean hasFourOfAKind() {


    }

    public boolean hasFullHouse() {



    }


    public boolean hasFlush() {
        int clubs = 0;
        int spades = 0;
        int hearts = 0;
        int diamonds = 0;

        for(Card current: allCards) {
            if(current.getCardSuit().equals("Spades")) {
                spades = spades + 1;
            } else if(current.getCardSuit().equals("Clubs")) {
                clubs = clubs + 1;
            } else if(current.getCardSuit().equals("Hearts")) {
                hearts = hearts + 1;
            } else if(current.getCardSuit().equals("Diamonds")) {
                diamonds = diamonds + 1;
            }
        }
        if(clubs>4 || spades>4 || hearts>4 || diamonds>4) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    public boolean hasStraight() {
        int cardsInRow = 1;
        int lastInStraight = allCards.get(0).getCardValue();
        for(int i=1; i<allCards.size(); i++) {
            if(allCards.get(i).getCardValue()==(lastInStraight+1)) {
                cardsInRow = cardsInRow + 1;
                lastInStraight = lastInStraight+1;
            } else if(allCards.get(i).getCardValue()!=lastInStraight) {
                cardsInRow = 1;
                lastInStraight = allCards.get(i).getCardValue();
            }
            if(lastInStraight == 13 && cardsInRow>3) {
                if(allCards.get(0).getCardValue()==1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (cardsInRow >4) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }


    public boolean hasThreeOfAKind() {
        for(int i=0; i<allCards.size()-2; i++) {
            if(allCards.get(i).isSameValue(allCards.get(i+1))) {
                if(allCards.get(i).isSameValue(allCards.get(i+2))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean hasTwoPair() {
        int numberOfPairs = 0;
        int valueOfFirstPair = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<allCards.size()-1; i++) {
            if(allCards.get(i).isSameValue(allCards.get(i+1))) {
                if(allCards.get(i).getCardValue()!=valueOfFirstPair) {
                    numberOfPairs = numberOfPairs + 1;
                    valueOfFirstPair = allCards.get(i).getCardValue();
                }
            }
            if(numberOfPairs>1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    public boolean hasPair() {
        for(int i=0; i<allCards.size()-1; i++) {
            if(allCards.get(i).isSameValue(allCards.get(i+1))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't make more than seven 7-card hands from a standard deck.

Comment: Thank you! This must be it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you're using a double-for loop to do this if what you're trying to find are the odds that someone has a flush in a seven-card hand. From what I can tell, the outer loop is what's giving you trouble here, because it's only asking for a new 7-card hand 7 times. To increase your sample size, I might try something like:

```
int count = 0;
int not_flush = 0;
int is_flush = 0;
while (count < 1000) {
    cards.clear();
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        cards.add(theDeck.dealCard());
    }
    seven = new SevenCardHand(cards);
    if (seven.hasFlush()) {
        is_flush++;
    }
    else {
        not_flush++;
    }
    count++;
}
float result = (float)is_flush/(float)not_flush;
```